# How can I know if my data better fits a power or a log curve?

Tags: curve-fitting

I have two arrays representing the independent and dependent variables in a certain experiment (1000 samples). I would like to know the functional relation between them. Specifically, I would like to decide between these two options:

- A logarithmic relation: $y = a * log^b(x) + c$.
- A power relation: $y = a * x^b + c$.

I use the `scipy.curve_fit` function as follows. For the logarithmic relation:

```
fit_func = lambda x,a,b,c: a * (np.log(x))**b + c
popt, pcov = curve_fit(fit_func, x, y)
plt.plot (x, fit_func(x, *popt))
```

For the power relation:

```
fit_func = lambda x,a,b,c: a * x**b + c
popt, pcov = curve_fit(fit_func, x, y)
plt.plot (x, fit_func(x, *popt))
```

In both cases, the plot overlaps the plot of the original data (y vs. x) very well. These are the values I get:

- For the logarithmic curve: [a,b,c] = [0.02520347 3.43184802 1.88396929]
- For the power curve: [a,b,c] = [ 0.70305951  0.49492494 -0.09505299]

Based on the plots, I cannot decide which model better describes the data.

Is there a better way to decide whether the logarithmic model or the power model is better?

Comment: Have a look at https://aaronclauset.github.io/powerlaws/ and the main reference therein

Comment: You have to establish a quantitative way to measure when one fit is "better" than another.  This is called a *loss function.*  Compare the values of your loss functions.

Comment: Some things to ponder: 1. Does it need to be either one or the other? It's possible to estimate a smooth relationship without pinning it down to these specific two, so why these, specifically? What's the purpose of the model? 2.  What are you assuming about the errors? Does that assumption make sense in your context? 3. Does your optimization criterion make the best use of the information in the data?

Comment: @Glen_b the experiment measures the performance of some algorithm. I would like to know if the performance is logarithmic (in O(poly(log(x))), or worse than that. So, if the performance is something like poly(log(x))+sqrt(x), it is not good, as it is not logarithmic. This is what I want to check: whether the relationship between y and x has any terms that are larger than logarithmic.

Comment: Usually an underlying theory or model of computation suggests the asymptotic behavior.   Because arbitrary polynomials in the log of $x$ cannot be distinguished from powers of $x,$ you appear to be attempting the impossible unless you can more specifically limit the class of asymptotic behaviors.  If you really are just choosing between the two behaviors stated in the question, often a plot of $(x,y)$ resolves the issue: one type of function fits all points well while the other does not.

Comment: What do you mean by "arbitrary polynomials in the log of x cannot be distinguished from powers of x"? Is it a formal statement?

Comment: Yes, because it amounts to asserting the exponential function can be estimated with arbitrary accuracy by polynomials.

Comment: @whuber I see... so what I wanted to do is impossible even in theory.